# Move A View from one side to another with React Native Shared Element and React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, expo, react-navigation

I Have a view (which is an imported component) on one page and would like to have a Transition of the view moving to the other side of the page (from left to right).

```
<SharedElement id="random">
                                        <View style={styles.thiStyle}>
                                                        <Imported Element/>
                                            </View>
                                        </SharedElement>
```